# Meteor: reactive: false not working

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am using Meteor with React and experiencing weird issue with **reactive:false**.

Here is what I am trying to do: The server has a collection 'Apps', and the client needs to get the 'Apps' based on what app-category the user chose. The first time the Apps are fetched, they should be sorted based on 'subscribeCount'. After that, the page should only re-render itself if the user choose another category and it should not re-render for 'subscribeCount' changes.

I tried to use reactive: false. However, I can't seem to stop the change of 'subscribeCount' from re-rendering the page.
Here is my code:

```js
getMeteorData(){
    const chosenApps = Apps.find({
            categoryNames: {
                $in: [this.state.chosenCategory]
            }
        },
        {sort: {subscribeCount: -1}, reactive: false}
    ).fetch();

    return {
        chosenApps: chosenApps,
    }
},


render(){
    console.log(this.data.chosenApps);
    return <div>
        ...
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Where is chosenApps itself being declared/set?

Comment: It is being declared in getMeteorData(){} function, it is a function that React use to get data from Meteor server and it runs right before the page render the first time.

Comment: The context of 'chosenApps' is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is why **reactive:false** didn't work for me:

I subscribed **more than one** collections in getMeteorData() method. Although I put **reactive: false** in one of the collections, when the other collections changes, the entire getMeteorData() method will be re-run, and that triggers all the collections to be fetched again.

To fix the problem, I moved the rest of the collections in a child component. And leave only the **reactive: false** collection in the current component.